# Bilingual site - when adding translations to Organic Group, prevent creating a separate group/content node

Tags: organic-groups, i18n-l10n

We have a bilingual site. We use organic groups to separate suborganisations and their members.

The Organic Group content's multilingual option is set to "Enabled, with translation"

We just want the "Landing" page of the Organic Group to be translated.

When the Organic Group is translated, it creates a discrete Group that allows users to join.

Essentially, we'd like everyone to be in the same group, but still be able to see content in their preferred language.

Anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer is to use Entity Translation. See here https://www.drupal.org/node/371181